# Is there a way to break the select if any channel is closed?

Tags: go

Let's say we are selecting on two channel. After running a few times, one of the channels is closed. How can I break out of the select?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    closed := make(chan bool, 1)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            ch <- 1
        }
        close(ch)
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case v := <-ch:
            fmt.Printf("v is %v\n", v)
        case <-closed:
            fmt.Println("The server is closed!")
            return
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Break!")
}
```

It is blocked infinitely. How to make it work?

Comment: `_, ok := <-closed` and checking for `!ok` ?

Comment: It's blocked because `ch` has the capacity of 0, and you attempt to send 5 values to it before attempting to close `closed` (I suppose you intended to use `close(closed)` instead of `close(ch)` — did you?).
Change the code to do `ch := make(chan int, 1)` then do a single send to `ch` then call `close(closed)` and you'll see it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code that:

1. Changed order of `select-case`. (*according to the comment from @zzn this behavior is random and it's better not to rely on this - better to check if channel has been closed*).
2. Writes to the `closed` channel

https://play.golang.org/p/K83XcPbr7b

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    closed := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
        close(ch)
    closed <- true
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case <- closed:
            fmt.Println("The server is closed!")
            return
        case v := <- ch:
            fmt.Printf("v is %v\n", v)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Break!")
}
```

If you don't change order of case there would be extra "zero" value: https://play.golang.org/p/JJaomKgqy8

Maybe it's better to check if channel has been closed?

https://play.golang.org/p/7Nd63b3JZ_

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
        close(ch)
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case v, hasMore := <- ch:
        if !hasMore {
            return
        }
            fmt.Printf("v is %v\n", v)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Break!")
}
```

Comment: I agree the first approach. The `ch` could be empty in a long time, but the `closed` can be closed at anytime.

Comment: `Changed order of select-case`,  `select` expression has no priority from top to bottom, it's random. please edit the answer

Comment: _Close_ your quit channels, do _not_ send on them.  Sending requires a receiver (unless buffered), closes do not.  In addition, closes can be received by _any_ number of receivers.

Answer (score 5):

You can return if the channel says it has no more items:

```
    case v, more := <-ch:
        if !more {
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("v is %v\n", v)
```